# How to add Projects to Default Window Working Set in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

by default eclipse uses the default "window working set".
On every startup this is chosen.
Unfortunately not all my projects (especcially those which are imported later) are not participating in the default window working set.
At the moment there are only two workarounds I know:
- deselect working set
- self-define a working set, include all projects and select this one
First: I just dont like to self define a working set, since I dont need such a feature
Second: I have to select/ deselect the working set every fkn startup.

When I start a searcha about "manage window working set" oder "add project to window working set" I only get those sites where it is explained how to self define a working set and how to manage it and that "window working set" is used by default.
I am not able to find anything on how to change the "window working set" itself.

Is there another way like editing some files manually to add my projects to it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Window Working Set' option in Package Explorer means that the working set specified in the main menu 'Window > Working Sets' is the one that is used. If you don't select a working set there then all projects are shown.

The 'Window > Working Sets' main menu item is not always shown. Use  'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' ('Window > Customize Perspective' before Eclipse 4.5) to enable this menu item if it is not visible

Comment: hi, sry for late ressponse
what you are saying is not new to me.
My question is about the default window working set.
When adding new or existinig Projects to the workspace I am able to add them to the "Default Window Working Set".

I want to know how to add a still in workspace existing Project to the default working set so that it also is shown when opening the workspace without the need of especially desecting working sets.

I dot want to delete and reimport it. I am lookgin for a defined way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh I musst revoke my last post
it seem I did not understand what you meant

I thought you meant deselect all from a special working set
but first I did not recognize that after enabling the menus as you described then at the list of project categories under the specific menu the single categories can be selected and deselected

I also did not know that this exactly describes the "window working set" (so I guess the name "window working set" comes from the category icons beeing placed under menue "window")

Comment: when deselecting one category such projects disappear from the navigation view (what is not what I want at first but...)

but when deselecting all (I first expected to get an empty project list) then all are shown and NOT hidden!

I never found this behavior documentated anywhere

thanks very much